# WP7 GPS startup data

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my WP7 project I am trying to obtain data from the GPS device. It works fine, but each time I start my application and ask for Latitude and Longitude values, GPS sensor returns me at the very beginning last values from the previous start. Should I flush data somehow on exit or on application startup?

Comment: if your application checks your stored data for the location, before trying to update it using the GeoCoordinateWatcher, then yes, you should flush it. You should take a look at [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_Sensors)

Comment: The point here is that I don't store location data from the previous start. Or this data is stored automatically? In this sample project I haven't found anything related to my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't trust the first value. See this article: http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/09/geo-location-on-wp7-dont-trust-first.html

Comment: Sorry, can't vote for your answer. It is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Yep, you need 15 reputation to upvote. However, you can, as with your other questions, accept them. (click the check-mark below the voting buttons).